# Angular 2 doesn't see changes in input

Tags: jquery, angular

I would like to put value into input using JQuery like this:

```
$('#documentValidityDateDay').val(dates.length ? dates[0].getDate() : '').trigger('input');
```

This is my html:

```
<input id="documentValidityDateYear" name="documentValidityDateYear" class="y-field" type="text" placeholder="rrrr" autocomplete="off" maxlength="4" formControlName="documentValidityDateYear"/>
```

When I try send data to component this fields are empty.

Comment: You should read more about Angular2 and why you should not use Jquery which is manipulation DOM elements with Angular2 which is not. These are not meant to be used together, and especially not in this use case.

Apart from that, you should check the Forms official documentation : 
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

Comment: Of course, you are right. I shouldn't use jquery but I got ready html and I have to connect angular. I have only problem with this datapicker. I don't have enaugh time to change everythink....